# Website or service to view a page without Javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy

Is there any website or service that allows you to submit a URL and displays the corresponding page with Javascript stripped out/disabled?

Clarification: This is to send a link to someone else to view (not in my own browser). Think of it like a JS-less bit.ly

Comment: What about disabling JavaScript in the actual browser? You can disable it completely .. or for some sites only, using browser extensions/plugins (like [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) for Firefox).

Comment: That definitely seems like the easiest way to go about this

Comment: Yeah I wanted to send a link to someone who probably isn't comfortable with messing with browser settings. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) has several options (including disabling JavaScript and Flash) and has a tons of different browsers/versions to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't difficult to do in-browser. From recollection in Opera you can press F12 and there is an option right there to disable Javascript. Other browsers may have add-ons which allow you to switch on and off quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2-Feb-19: Use Google Web Light which has functionality similar to Mobilizer - https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url={URL to transcode}

More info here - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en

Info below is now obsolete -

Try [Google Mobilizer](http://www.google.com/gwt/n)

It [generates proxied, mobile-friendly web pages](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/10/read-proxied-mobile-friendly-web-pages.html) for URLs you submit to it. I tried out several different websites with this service and noticed (by running Developer Tools in Chrome via F12 shortcut) that it shows the original content/text of the target URL without making use of any JavaScript even though the original URL may use JS.

I built a [Google Mobilizer Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) that can be used to view just the text of web pages.

Comment: Google Mobilizer link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a browser plugin.  For Firefox the NoScript https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/ plugin will disable JavaScript and allow it to be re-enabled on a site by site basis if it is needed.  Google Chrome user have ScriptSafe https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en this offers similar functionality.  This may be the best option and is easy for novice users to install.